# Failed to launch chrome [FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(116)] No usable sandbox

Tags: node.js, linux, puppeteer, redhat

> Failed to launch chrome!\n[0702/102126.236473:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(116)] No usable sandbox! Update your kernel or see https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_suid_sandbox_development.md for more information on developing with the SUID sandbox. If you want to live dangerously and need an immediate workaround, you can try using --no-sandbox.\n#0 0x55e0286ccaf9 ... Core file will not be generated.\n\n\nTROUBLESHOOTING: [https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md\n\n](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md%5Cn%5Cn) at onClose (/home/ec2-user/credence/microservices/reporting-server/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:342:14)\n at Interface.helper.addEventListener (/home/ec2-user/credence/microservices/reporting-server/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:331:50)\n at Interface.emit (events.js:203:15)\n at Interface.close (readline.js:397:8)\n at Socket.onend (readline.js:173:10)\n at Socket.emit (events.js:203:15)\n at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1143:12)\n at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

Answer (score 5):

While launching puppeteer , pass the  argument `--no-sandbox`:

```js
await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox'] })
```

Comment: Be aware that as the [https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md](puppeteer docs) are saying you should only use this in exceptional cases.

`If you absolutely trust the content you open in Chrome, you can launch Chrome with the --no-sandbox argument`